# Tirar duplicidade ignorando uma coluna com informação distinta

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Dei uma procurada aqui e não achei nada parecido.

Quando efetuo o seguinte Select :

```
SELECT  
    a.idEmpregadoReserva as Controle
    ,(select EmpresaAplicativo from tbEmpresaAplicativo where tbEmpresaAplicativo.idEmpresaAplicativo = c.idEmpresaAplicativo) Colonia
    ,d.Nome
    ,d.Matricula


    ,a.NumeroDocumento as [Numero Voucher]
    ,e.ValorVoucher
    ,f.TipoVoucher 
    ,c.idReserva
    ,(select tipoformapagto from tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto where tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto.idTipoFormaPagto = a.idTipoFormaPagto) [Forma Pagamento]
  FROM [APCEF].[dbo].[tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Financeiro] a join tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Reserva b on a.idEmpregadoReserva = b.idEmpregadoReserva
   join tbHPG_Reserva c on b.idReserva = c.idReserva join tbEmpregado d on c.idEmpregado = d.idEmpregado join tbEmpregadoVoucher e
    on a.NumeroDocumento = e.idEmpregadoVoucher
    join tbTipoVoucher f on e.idTipoVoucher = f.idTipoVoucher
  where c.DataEntrada between '2019-01-23' and '2019-01-27' and (c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 4 or c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 5) 
  and a.idTipoFormaPagto = 1
```

E aparece o seguinte :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem eu gostaria fazer um select como se fosse um select DISTINCT porem ignorando o IDRESERVA, ou seja puxando apenas 1 Numero de voucher ( ele não pode repetir )

Comment: coloca o código do select pra nós por favor, poder dar crtl+c

Comment: @GermanoBussNiehues Fiz a substituição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda, essa query é para ***SQL SERVER***

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  
    a.idEmpregadoReserva as Controle
    ,(select EmpresaAplicativo from tbEmpresaAplicativo where tbEmpresaAplicativo.idEmpresaAplicativo = c.idEmpresaAplicativo) Colonia
    ,d.Nome
    ,d.Matricula


    ,a.NumeroDocumento as [Numero Voucher]
    ,e.ValorVoucher
    ,f.TipoVoucher 
    ,c.idReserva
    ,(select tipoformapagto from tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto where tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto.idTipoFormaPagto = a.idTipoFormaPagto) [Forma Pagamento]
    ,row_number() over(partition by a.NumeroDocumento order by (select null)) as rn
  FROM [APCEF].[dbo].[tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Financeiro] a join tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Reserva b on a.idEmpregadoReserva = b.idEmpregadoReserva
   join tbHPG_Reserva c on b.idReserva = c.idReserva join tbEmpregado d on c.idEmpregado = d.idEmpregado join tbEmpregadoVoucher e
    on a.NumeroDocumento = e.idEmpregadoVoucher
    join tbTipoVoucher f on e.idTipoVoucher = f.idTipoVoucher
  where c.DataEntrada between '2019-01-23' and '2019-01-27' and (c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 4 or c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 5) 
  and a.idTipoFormaPagto = 1) A
  WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Cara funcionou, Poderia me explicar o que foi feito com esse sub select dentro do select ?  Você meio que atribuiu o numero documento como um 'contador' e pediu para mostrar apenas o primeiro ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  
        a.idEmpregadoReserva as Controle
        ,(select EmpresaAplicativo from tbEmpresaAplicativo where tbEmpresaAplicativo.idEmpresaAplicativo = c.idEmpresaAplicativo) Colonia
        ,d.Nome
        ,d.Matricula


        ,a.NumeroDocumento as [Numero Voucher]
        ,e.ValorVoucher
        ,f.TipoVoucher 
        ,wm_concat(c.idReserva) as ids_de_reservas
        ,(select tipoformapagto from tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto where tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto.idTipoFormaPagto = a.idTipoFormaPagto) [Forma Pagamento]
      FROM [APCEF].[dbo].[tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Financeiro] a join tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Reserva b on a.idEmpregadoReserva = b.idEmpregadoReserva
       join tbHPG_Reserva c on b.idReserva = c.idReserva join tbEmpregado d on c.idEmpregado = d.idEmpregado join tbEmpregadoVoucher e
        on a.NumeroDocumento = e.idEmpregadoVoucher
        join tbTipoVoucher f on e.idTipoVoucher = f.idTipoVoucher
      where c.DataEntrada between '2019-01-23' and '2019-01-27' and (c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 4 or c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 5) 
      and a.idTipoFormaPagto = 1

group by
 a.idEmpregadoReserva
        ,(select EmpresaAplicativo from tbEmpresaAplicativo where tbEmpresaAplicativo.idEmpresaAplicativo = c.idEmpresaAplicativo)
        ,d.Nome
        ,d.Matricula
        ,a.NumeroDocumento
        ,e.ValorVoucher
        ,f.TipoVoucher ,
      (select tipoformapagto from tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto where tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto.idTipoFormaPagto = a.idTipoFormaPagto)
```

Se eu entendi sua pergunta e a estrutura do seu banco seria isso, espero que funcione =D.

Obs.: Se for MySQL e não funcionar troca o `wm_concat` por `concat_ws`

Comment: Não funcionou nem com wm_concat e concat_ws 

e não alterando o select da reserva da erro no group by